# Is that possible for a system to have an equilibrium point at infinity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, systems-of-equations, infinity

I know for some system of ODEs, there is no  equilibrium at all, but I am wording that is valid to say a system has equilibrium at $\infty$? Consider the following system as an example.
$$x' = \frac{y}{x}$$
$$y' = y - 4$$
So for this system, if we want to solve the equilibrium point, we need to solve the system of equation
$$\frac{y}{x} = 0$$
$$y - 4 = 0$$ which give us $y = 4$ and $ 4/x = 0$. So the only way for the first equation to be zero is as $x$ approaching $\infty$
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{4}{x} = 0$$
but can we say $(\infty, 4)$ is an equilibrium point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, because $\infty$ or $\pm\infty$ is not a point on the real line, it is a symbol to help with convergence or divergence statements.

What you could do is to compactify the real line to an interval with end-points (corona) or to a circle (one-point compactification). Then you could speak of convergence to these newly added points in the modified topology.

But in the traditional sense, your system does not have equilibrium points.

Comment: In my beginner analysis class I was told about the extended real line  which sounds like the endpoints.

Comment: Yes, and then you have to extend the topology so that "convergence to $\pm\infty$" is given a normal sense. Or you could just transform, like with $x=\tan(u)$, to get $\frac{u'}{\cos^2u}=\frac{y}{\tan(u)}$ or $u'=\frac{y\cos^3u}{\sin u}$, which then has more traditional equilibrium points at $u=\pm\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Yeah, it make sense, but if I use the limit argument carefully,  can I say the system equilibrium only as the x approaching $\infty$?

Comment: You can say anything if you formulate it clearly enough, and if possible highlight the exceptional nature. It is only when you have to build on existing definitions that you have to be careful to not imply something incorrect. You then get something like a "basic truth" version and a "higher truth" version.